# How to arrange five blocks on UI

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, human-interface-guideline, hci

I have five blocks on UI:

[image]

On the basis of rights of user, these blocks will be visible. For example, if an Admin signs in, all blocks will be visible.

- For Manager, I want to show block# 2,4 and 5.
- For Team Lead, I want to show block# 1 and 4.
- For Supervisor, I want to show block#1,3,4,5.
  And there could be multiple options (a maximum of 2^5).

Currently, I am doing it hard-coded. e.g for Manager, arrangement is defined to be like this:

[image]

but currently there is no logic for this arrangement. Should I follow a proper logic/formula for arranging blocks? Or should I decide it how each combination of block will be arranged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are those blocks? Do they contain graphic images, or UI elements, or something else?
Is it a desktop application, a mobile app or a web application?

Comment: These are basically different modules of an application e.g: Paint, Editor etc. These are clickable. By clicking on block1, user will be taken to Painting Module, and by clicking on Block2 user will be taken to editor.
Currently, this is a web application, but will be supported for mobiles in future.

Comment: Just to check, are all the blocks the same size?

Answer (score 3):

On the image I shown the two best ways you can show 5 boxes the first one you use if the boxes are the same size and the second on you use if the boxes or not the same size.

[image: On the image I shown the two best ways you can show 5 boxes the first one you use if the boxes are the same size and the second on you use if the boxes or not the same size.]

Answer (score 2):

How about just putting them next to each other, starting from left. If a row is filled you start a next row. Basically the way that iCloud.com does it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a little creative with it, re-numbered perhaps not in the order you want but it will help make the format look better if you are hard coding the placements. I have a demo setup [here](http://ke4beg.axshare.com). It shows the combinations you are saying you will use along with the overall 1-5 setup. I know it's a little unconventional but it might fit your needs the best by getting a little outside the box. Hope this helps.